# Apply gradient while GlideImage is loading on JetpackCompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-glide

I want to apply a gradient as the loading state to the GlideImage while the image is loading. How can I do this?

Currently I'm placing a Gradient Box and the image inside, but this doesn't work for images with no background.

My current code is:

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier.background(
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                listOf(
                    Gray,
                    Color.White
                )
            )
        )
    ) {
        GlideImage(
            model = banner.imageUrl,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
            modifier = Modifier.coloredShadow(ShadowBannerImage, 0.28f)
        )
    }
```

For example, this case, it receives a PNG image and, since GlideImage is inside a box with gradient, the gradient will appear behind image, producing a effect that image as background, what is not supposed to happen. The image should only have background while Glide is loading it.

[image]

Comment: `but this doesn't work for images with no background.` can you explain this a bit

Comment: @Javlon Hi Javlon, sure! Edited the question and updated with a screenshot of what is happening and tried to describe that piece of words.

Comment: Are you using `bumptech` glide or `landscapist` one?

Comment: @Javlon bumptech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `bumptech` glide [doesn't support placeholders or loading composables](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/compose.html#transitions-and-state-changes).

> Similary while Glide’s placeholder, error and fallback request options work and can be provided via GlideImage’s RequestBuilderTransform, we do not currently support custom Composable functions for each of those states.

So I suggest you to use [landscapist](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist). And it is signature is like this:

```
@Composable
public fun GlideImage(
    imageModel: () -> Any?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    glideRequestType: GlideRequestType = GlideRequestType.DRAWABLE,
    requestBuilder: @Composable () -> RequestBuilder<*> = {
        LocalGlideProvider.getGlideRequestBuilder()
    },
    requestOptions: @Composable () -> RequestOptions = {
        LocalGlideProvider.getGlideRequestOptions()
    },
    requestListener: (() -> RequestListener<Any>)? = null,
    component: ImageComponent = rememberImageComponent {},
    imageOptions: ImageOptions = ImageOptions(),
    onImageStateChanged: (GlideImageState) -> Unit = {},
    @DrawableRes previewPlaceholder: Int = 0,
    loading: @Composable (BoxScope.(imageState: GlideImageState.Loading) -> Unit)? = null,
    success: @Composable (BoxScope.(imageState: GlideImageState.Success) -> Unit)? = null,
    failure: @Composable (BoxScope.(imageState: GlideImageState.Failure) -> Unit)? = null
)
```

You can set your gradient composable to loading parameter of `GlideImage` :

```
 GlideImage(
    ...
    loading = Box( modifier = Modifier.background(
                        brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                          listOf(Gray, Color.White)
                        ))
                 ) 
 )
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.